# Displaying Application File Path in Label VB.net

Tags: vb.net, filepath

I am trying to find a way (for debugging purposes) to have my application display the full path of where the application is executing from to a label on my main form.

Code example -

Label34.Text = Filepath (or something similar)

What do I need to assign the Label text to so that it displays the full path of the running application?

Comment: Sorry, never saw the previous answers before

Comment: I googled "full path of where the application is executing" and got a couple great hits for StackOverflow, albeit C#

Comment: @AFriend, yeah sorry.  I shouldn't have posted here probably...